# How to stretch parent element width in layout with ant-design

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, antd

[Demo](https://codepen.io/DrakeXiang/pen/EwXrmW?editors=0010) here.

```
<div style={{width: 2000, background: 'red'}}>content</div>
```

The parent div is not affected by the child width, maybe because it's flex? Then how should I set the parent width according to its child's width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `align-items: flex-start` to the *parent* container (the default value *stretch* causes the `Content` width to be *restricted*):

```
<Layout className="layout" style={{ padding: '0 24px 24px' }}>
    <Breadcrumb style={{ margin: '12px 0' }}>
      <Breadcrumb.Item>Home</Breadcrumb.Item>
      <Breadcrumb.Item>List</Breadcrumb.Item>
      <Breadcrumb.Item>App</Breadcrumb.Item>
    </Breadcrumb>
    <Content style={{background: '#fff', padding: 24, margin: 0, minHeight: 280}}>
      <div style={{width: 2000, background: 'red'}}>content</div>
    </Content>
</Layout>
```

with style:

```
.layout {
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

See [`updated codepen`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NagozK).

Comment: Thanks for answering, I just scratched my head about this problem, I was focusing on the direct parent of my content, didn't realize its ancestor could be the real cause..